# Node JS process.nextTick and setTimeout

Tags: node.js, settimeout, event-loop

After read document about the Node JS event loop at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/. I've tried to run this code to understand more:

```
//setTimeout 1
setTimeout(function A (){
    console.log('timeout 1 called!!!');
    process.nextTick(function E (){
        console.log('tick called');
    })
});
//setTimeout 2
setTimeout(function B (){
    console.log('timeout 2 called!!!');
});
```

And the results is unpredictable, when I've tried to run this code multiple times, sometime the result is:

```
timeout 1 called!!!
timeout 2 called!!!
tick called
```

But sometime it could be:

```
timeout 1 called!!!
tick called
timeout 2 called!!!
```

By my understanding, this has happened because of process.nextTick run after each phase of event loop complete.

So, if call stack has completed, there has 2 cases will be happened:

1. NodeJS API complete resolve setTimeout 1, added function A to timer queue in timer phase of event loop and event loop start before NodeJS API complete resolve setTimeout 2. That's mean function E will be added to nextTickQueue before function B added to timers queue => after function A complete, timer queue empty (timers phase complete) => nextTickQueue called => The result is:

> ```
> timeout 1 called!!!
> tick called!!!
> timeout 2 called!!!
> ```

2. NodeJS API complete resolve setTimeout 1, added function A to timer queue in timer phase of event loop and NodeJS API complete resolve setTimeout 2 after that, added function B to timer queue before event loop start. So the event loop will execute all callback functions in timers queue to complete timer phase, so the nextTickQueue will be resolve after timeout 1, and timeout 2 complete. And the result is:

> ```
> timeout 1 called!!!
> timeout 2 called!!!
> tick called!!!
> ```

Am i understanding right? Could you guys please help me to clarify this?
Thanks :).

Comment: Does this still happen ? Which node version ? Are you using modules is some way, like is it a .mjs file ? I can not reproduce this (nextTick is always executed before setTimeout 2).

Answer (score 2):

> By my understanding, this has happened because of `process.nextTick` run
>   after each phase of event loop complete.

No `process.nextTick` are executed before the end of every phase and before the beginning of the next.

**That output is *non deterministic*. You cannot guarantee the order of execution for above. All you can do is reason about it based on its output.**

So, if call stack has completed, there has 2 cases will be happened:

> NodeJS API complete resolve setTimeout 1, added function A to timer
>   queue in timer phase of event loop and <s>event loop start before NodeJS
>   API complete resolve setTimeout 2</s>. That's mean function E will be
>   added to nextTickQueue before function B added to timers queue =>
>   after function A complete, timer queue empty (timers phase complete)
>   => nextTickQueue called => The result is:

Once You Start Your node.js process event loop starts. A more appropriate term would have been `event loop moves to the nextPhase before setTimeout2 resolves`

Rest All reason presented by you are fine apart for few technical terminology used. But that's ok !